# Setting pylintrc path in pylinter for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

I've got Sublime Text 2 (+ the pylinter package) and pylint installed, but can't get the `pylint_path` setting to work; my `Pylinter.sublime-settings` file looks like:

```
{
  "verbose":true,
  "message_stay": true,
  "pylint_path": "Z:\\python\\pylintrc"
}
```

but when I run pylint I get the following output:

```
 - PyLinter: Verbose is True
 - PyLinter: Running Pylinter on Z:\TestProject\test.py
 - PyLinter: Current PYTHONPATH is ''
 - PyLinter: Updated PYTHONPATH is ''
 - PyLinter: Running command with Pylint (1, 4, 1)
 - PyLinter: python Z:\python\pylintrc --reports=n --msg-template={path}:{line}:{msg_id}:{msg} --disable=C0303 Z:\TestProject\test.py
error: Fatal pylint error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
- PyLinter: No errors found
```

but I've put errors in to prove to myself it works (or doesn't..)! If I remove the `pylint_path` setting, it works and the errors do get reported. (For completion, I've tried `Z:/TestProject/test.py` and Z:\TestProject\test.py too, and get the same result each time)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a long time ago, but I just stumbled across it from google.

You want to set pylint_rc instead of pylint_path.

From the default settings:

```
// Full path to the lint.py module in the pylint package
"pylint_path": null,
// Optional full path to a Pylint configuration file
"pylint_rc": null,
```